Spreading points evenly along an existing curve in SwiftUI
Im new to coding so I have been taking (a lot of)help from ChatGPT. I have a curve(blue) in a chart that i have defined with a few points. I also have something i Call Nick's(black dots). Right now the Nicks are spread evenly over time until midnight. every time a press a button one nick is deducted the rest get redistributed from that time until midnight. But, I want the Nicks to be spread evenly along the curve, that would automatically place them closer to each other where the incline is high, and more apart where the curve is flat. but i cant seem to get it to work. if you think you know how to fix this please be very descriptive in your explanation since Im a noob(Im trying to learn). not exactly sure what code snippets to share so im sharing the whole script. there are some posts about this already, but i dont understand the solutions.
thanks
import SwiftUI
import Charts  // Import the Charts framework
import NotificationCenter

struct TimerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationManager: NavigationManager
    @State private var showConfirmationDialog = false
    @State private var totalCost: Float = 0.0
    @State private var nicksLeft: Int = StorageManager.shared.getNicksInPack()
    @State private var dailyUse: Int = StorageManager.shared.getDailyUse()
    @State private var NicksLeftToday: Int = StorageManager.shared.getNicksLeftToday()  // Load on init
    @State private var isFirstPressOfTheDay: Bool = true
    @State private var daysLeft: Int = StorageManager.shared.getDaysLeft()
    @State private var firstPressTime: Date? = StorageManager.shared.getFirstPressTime() // Load firstPressTime from StorageManager
    @State private var graphData: [TimeSeriesData] = []  // Data for the graph
    @State private var selectedPoison: String = StorageManager.shared.getPoisonChoice() ?? "item"

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 86400, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let firstTime = firstPressTime {
                Chart(graphData) { data in
                    if data.isNick {
                        PointMark(
                            x: .value("Time", data.time),
                            y: .value("Value", data.value)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.black)  // Style for the nick points
                    } else {
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Time", data.time),
                            y: .value("Value", data.value)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)  // Style for the curve
                        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                    }
                }
                .chartXAxis {
                    AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: Calendar.Component.hour)) {
                        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.hour())
                    }
                }
                .chartYAxis {
                    AxisMarks()
                }
                .frame(height: 200)
                .background(Color.white)  // Set a background color
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))  // Clip the background to rounded corners
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)  // Add a gray border with 1 point line width
                )
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 25)  // Apply padding to the sides
                .padding(.top, 75)  // Apply more padding to the top
            }

            // Display the total cost
            Text("Total cost: \(totalCost, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .bold()
                .padding()

            // Display days left
            Text("\(daysLeft) days left")
                .bold()
                .padding()

            // Large button with a pressed state
            Button(action: {
                if StorageManager.shared.hasStartButtonBeenPressed() {
                    if !isFirstPressOfTheDay {
                        addCost()
                    }
                    if isFirstPressOfTheDay {
                        NicksLeftToday = dailyUse
                        isFirstPressOfTheDay = false
                        firstPressTime = Date()  // Set the first press time
                        StorageManager.shared.saveFirstPressTime(firstPressTime!) // Save firstPressTime to StorageManager
                    }
                    
                    if NicksLeftToday > 0 {
                        NicksLeftToday -= 1
                        StorageManager.shared.saveNicksLeftToday(NicksLeftToday)  // Save every time it updates
                    }
                    
                    if dailyUse > 0 {
                        dailyUse -= 1
                        StorageManager.shared.saveDailyUse(dailyUse)
                    }
                    
                    updateGraphData()  // Update the graph data after modifying the nicks left
                } else {
                    navigationManager.currentView = "PickYourPoisonView"
                    StorageManager.shared.saveStartButtonPressed(true)
                }
            }) {
                Text(StorageManager.shared.hasStartButtonBeenPressed() ? "Take one" : "Let's Get Started")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .padding()

            // Mulligan buttons
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Button("Mulligan") {
                        addCost()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                showConfirmationDialog = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .alert(isPresented: $showConfirmationDialog) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Confirm"),
                    message: Text("Are you sure you want to erase all data and start over?"),
                    primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Yes")) {
                        StorageManager.shared.clearAllData {
                            daysLeft = 0
                            totalCost = 0.0
                            NicksLeftToday = 0
                        }
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel()
                )
            }
            
            // Fetch and display daily use and selected poison
            Text("\(NicksLeftToday) \(selectedPoison) left today")
                .bold()
                .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            graphData = StorageManager.shared.getGraphData()
            updateData()
            firstPressTime = StorageManager.shared.getFirstPressTime() // Load firstPressTime from StorageManager
            totalCost = StorageManager.shared.getTotalCost()
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
            updateData()
        }
    }

    private func addCost() {
        let costPerPack = StorageManager.shared.getCostPerPack()
        let nicksInPack = StorageManager.shared.getNicksInPack()
        let costPerNick = nicksInPack > 0 ? costPerPack / Float(nicksInPack) : 0
        totalCost += costPerNick
        StorageManager.shared.saveTotalCost(totalCost)
    }

    private func updateGraphData() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let now = firstPressTime ?? Date()
        let endOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now)!)

        // Total hours from now to midnight
        let totalHours = endOfDay.timeIntervalSince(now) / 3600

        // Define your custom curve data points
        let customDataPoints: [GraphDataPoint] = [
            GraphDataPoint(x: 0, y: 10),
            GraphDataPoint(x: 3, y: 4),
            GraphDataPoint(x: 9, y: 4),
            GraphDataPoint(x: 14, y: 20),
            GraphDataPoint(x: 18, y: 3)
        ]

        // Maximum x value from custom data points
        let maxX = customDataPoints.map { $0.x }.max() ?? 18  // Default to 18 if no points

        // Map custom data points to TimeSeriesData, scaling x values to fit from now to midnight
        graphData = customDataPoints.map { point in
            let scaledX = point.x / maxX * totalHours
            let time = Date(timeInterval: scaledX * 3600, since: now)
            return TimeSeriesData(time: time, value: point.y)
        }

        // Add nicks as black dots along the curve
        if NicksLeftToday > 0 {
            let intervals = totalHours / Double(NicksLeftToday)
            for i in 1...NicksLeftToday {
                let nickTime = Date(timeInterval: intervals * Double(i) * 3600, since: now)
                let nickValue = interpolateValue(at: nickTime, using: graphData)
                graphData.append(TimeSeriesData(time: nickTime, value: nickValue, isNick: true))
            }
        }

        // Ensure the curve stretches to midnight by adding a last point at the end of the day
        if let lastPoint = graphData.last, lastPoint.time != endOfDay {
            graphData.append(TimeSeriesData(time: endOfDay, value: lastPoint.value))
        }
        StorageManager.shared.saveGraphData(graphData)
    }

    private func interpolateValue(at time: Date, using dataPoints: [TimeSeriesData]) -> Double {
        let sortedPoints = dataPoints.sorted { $0.time < $1.time }
        for i in 0..<sortedPoints.count - 1 {
            let current = sortedPoints[i]
            let next = sortedPoints[i + 1]
            if time >= current.time && time <= next.time {
                let fraction = (time.timeIntervalSince(current.time)) / (next.time.timeIntervalSince(current.time))
                return current.value + fraction * (next.value - current.value)
            }
        }
        return sortedPoints.last?.value ?? 0
    }

    private func updateData() {
        NicksLeftToday = StorageManager.shared.getNicksLeftToday()
        selectedPoison = StorageManager.shared.getPoisonChoice() ?? "item"
    }
}

struct TimeSeriesData: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID
    let time: Date
    let value: Double
    var isNick: Bool  // Add this line to indicate if the point is a nick

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), time: Date, value: Double, isNick: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.time = time
        self.value = value
        self.isNick = isNick
    }
}

struct GraphDataPoint: Codable {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
}

struct TimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimerView()
    }
}



